# Recurrence Relation General Formula Using Power Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Several sources propose finding a general formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of a sequence defined by a recurrence relation by assuming the term is defined by a power function.

E.g. consider the Fibonacci numbers:

$$u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_n$$

$$u_0=u_1=1$$

Let $u_n=kx^n$:

$$x^2=x+1$$

$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

At this point it is usually stated that the double root implies two forms for $u_n$, both of which satisfy the recurrence.

$$u_{n1}=k_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

$$u_{n2}=k_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

Therefore the most general solution is a combinaton of the above two:

$$u_n=k_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n + k_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

My question is - how can this step be justified? If you check on $u_{n1}$ being a general formula, it does not check out as you get inconsistent values for $k_1$ if $u_0$ and $u_1$ are considered:

$$u_0=k_1=1$$

$$u_1=k_1\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=1 => k_1 = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$$

So this must mean the original assumption of $u_n=kx^n$ is incorrect in the first place?

Comment: $u_0$ means $n=0$ and $\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^0=1$

Comment: @Raffaele Yes so that means $k_1=1$, and that $u_1$=$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which is incorrect?

Comment: No, $u_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1$ which is stated in the initial conditions. It looks like you are a little confused. Why should be $k_1=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}?$

Comment: @Raffaele You are not reading my question correctly - I am looking at solution $u_{n1}$ only - it needs to satisfy the recurrence relation on its own before you can claim $u_{n1}+u_{n2}$ does too right? (this also assumes $u_{n2}$ can satisfy the relation on its own as well)

Comment: You are wrong: it doesn't work like that. Look here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/discrete_mathematics/discrete_mathematics_recurrence_relation.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood the purpose of $k_1$ and $k_2$: they serve to pick out one of the infinitely many sequences satisfying the recurrence

$$u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_n\,.\tag{1}$$

Let $\Sigma$ be the vector space of all sequences of real numbers; vector addition is defined termwise, so that

$$\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle+\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle x_n+y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\,.$$

The sequences satisfying $(1)$ turn out to be a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Sigma$. Let $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$ and $\hat\varphi=\frac12\left(1-\sqrt5\right)$, the two zeroes of $x^2-x-1=0$. Then the sequence $\langle\varphi^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle\hat\varphi^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are linearly independent sequences satisfying $(1)$, so every sequence satisfying $(1)$ is a linear combination of these two sequences. Thus, if $v=\langle v_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a particular sequence satisfying $(1)$, there are constants $k_1$ and $k_2$, depending on $v$ such that

$$v_n=k_1\varphi^n+k_2\hat\varphi^n\tag{2}$$

for each $n\in\Bbb N$. One uses the initial values $v_0$ and $v_1$ to find $k_1$ and $k_2$.

The point here is that these values of $k_1$ and $k_2$ apply only to the specific sequence determined by the initial values $v_0$ and $v_1$. If $v_0=1$ and $v_1=\varphi$, then $k_1=1$ and $k_2=0$, and we get the sequence of powers of $\varphi$. If $v_0=1$ and $v_1=1$, substituting $n=0$ and $n=1$ into $(2)$ shows that $k_1+k_2=1$ and $k_1\varphi+k_2\hat\varphi=1$, and we get a very different pair of values for $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Comment: My question is how can we justify going from the original assumption of $u_n=kx^n$ to $u_n=k_1\phi_1^n+k_2\phi_2^n$ (where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the two roots derived above)

Comment: @vwap: That is not the argument that is actually employed, though it’s possible that you found sources that either present the actual argument poorly or offer a rather hand-wavy substitute for it.

Comment: I saw this method in 'An Imaginary Tale' by Paul Nahin, where he found a general form for $u_n$ satisfying $u_{n+2}=4u_{n+1}-8u_n$. Substituting $u_n=kz^n$ yields a double root for $z$, i.e. two possible $u_n$. The author writes - '_So, which $u_n$ should we use? The most general solution is to use both, as a sum_'. Then he asks the reader to follow the same method to find a general formula for the fibonacci sequence. So you are saying he has left some logic unstated?

How is the choice of $u_n=k_1\phi_1^n+k_2\phi_2^n$ justified from first principles?

Comment: @vwap: Okay; he’s made a true assertion but not offered any proof and only the barest hint of an intuitive justification. The actual proof follows the lines that I sketched in my answer. If $S$ is the set of sequences satisfying $(1)$, one first proves that $S$ is a subspace of the vector space $\Sigma$ and that the sequences $\langle\varphi^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle\hat\varphi^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ are in $S$. One then shows that for every possible pair of initial values $v_0$ and $v_1$ there are constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $\langle v_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ satisfies $(1)$, ...

Comment: ... where $v_n$ is given by $(2)$. But it’s clear that every member of $S$ is completely determined by its first two terms, so this shows that every member of $S$ can be obtained in this way as a linear combination of $\langle\varphi^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle\hat\varphi^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - the key part of your proof is the identification of $\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}} {2}\right)^n$ as the basis of the vector space - can you explain how that is derived? I.e. why would the roots of the equation $x^2-x-1=0$ help in identifying the basis?

Comment: @vwap: See if [this PDF](https://math.berkeley.edu/~arash/55/8_2.pdf) answers your remaining questions. [This one](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~elenas/CS111/linear_recurrences.pdf) covers much of the same ground in a less formal way but stops short of stating the general results.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks!

Comment: @vwap: You’re welcome!